# date conversion mktime returns wrong date

Tags: php

I got this code

```
<?php
function dateFunc($month)
{
  setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');
  $monthSub = date('m',strtotime($month));
  $name=strftime("%B",mktime(0,0,0,$monthSub,1,2000));
  $name = $name.' '.date('Y', strtotime($month));
  return strtoupper($name);
}
$output ="";


$output.=
dateFunc(date('Y-m', strtotime('-1 month'))).'<br>
'.dateFunc(date('Y-m', strtotime('-2 month'))).'<br>
'.dateFunc(date('Y-m', strtotime('-3 month'))).'<br>
'.dateFunc(date('Y-m', strtotime('-4 month'))).'<br>
'.dateFunc(date('Y-m', strtotime('-5 month'))).'<br>';

echo $output;
?>
```

The output is

```
JULIO 2017
MAYO 2017
MAYO 2017
MARZO 2017
MARZO 2017
```

I´m expecting this output

```
JULIO 2017
JUNIO 2017
MAYO 2017
ABRIL 2017
MARZO 2017
```

Some day I read the problem, the conflict comes on 30 days  month´s and the `mktime()` needs another parameter but I don´t remember how to fix it.

Suggestions please...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I might go about it.
https://iconoun.com/demo/temp_alberto.php

```html
<?php // demo/temp_alberto.php
/**
 * Month computations
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422134/date-conversion-mktime-returns-wrong-date
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';


function lastMonth($date='next month')
{
    $m = date('Y-m-1', strtotime($date));
    $x = date('F Y', strtotime($m . '- 1 day'));
    return strtoupper($x);
}

$out = NULL;

$lm = lastmonth();
$out .= PHP_EOL . $lm;

$lm = lastmonth($lm);
$out .= PHP_EOL . $lm;

$lm = lastmonth($lm);
$out .= PHP_EOL . $lm;

$lm = lastmonth($lm);
$out .= PHP_EOL . $lm;

$lm = lastmonth($lm);
$out .= PHP_EOL . $lm;

echo $out;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$output.=
dateFunc((new DateTime(date("Y-m-1")))->modify("-5 month")->format("Y-m"));
echo $output;
```

Comment: @alberto-siurob please accept the answer that helped you.